# C# Include Derived Control in Toolbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, textbox

This is in reference to my other question [Auto Clearing Textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110/c-auto-clearing-winform-textbox).
If I choose to derive a new TextBox control from TextBox instead of implement a user control just containing my Textbox, how would I include that in the toolbox.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Right-click the toolbox, click "Choose
>   Items" from the context menu, browse
>   to your DLL, and select it.

To extend on Greg's answer...
Just to clarify, you cannot add a user control to the tool box if the code for it is in the same project that you want to use it in.  For some reason MS has never added this ability, which would make sense since we don't want to always have to create a User Control Library DLL everytime we want to use a user control.  So, to get it in your tool box, you have to first create a separate "User Control Library" project (which *can* be in the same solution!) and then do what Greg said.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the toolbox, click "Choose Items" from the context menu, browse to your DLL, and select it.